# gatsby build error while gatsby develop works fine Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

```js
<--- Last few GCs --->

[16184:00000237DCD7CC20]    88497 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2041.4 (2054.4) -> 2041.0 (2054.2) MB, 6714.0 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.053, current mu = 0.001) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[16184:00000237DCD7CC20]    94059 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2042.0 (2051.2) -> 2041.6 (2052.9) MB, 5546.7 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.027, current mu = 0.003) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7B2A6412F napi_wrap+133311
 2: 00007FF7B29FDD06 SSL_get_quiet_shutdown+63062
 3: 00007FF7B29FEB9D node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF7B32E19CE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF7B32C67BD v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF7B316FFCC v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF7B317B3EA v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1258
 8: 00007FF7B3178529 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2457
 9: 00007FF7B316D0C1 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2049
10: 00007FF7B316B2C5 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1349
11: 00007FF7B318B73B v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+203
12: 00007FF7B2EB9F81 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1409
13: 00007FF7B336CDFD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+474253
14: 00007FF7B33046BD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+46413
15: 0000013BF1A43736
```

gatsby develop is working fine and the local site is running fine. but not able to use gatsby build

Answer (score 0):

There was an `await` call for a library inside a function, so it was acting like a loop. Thus the error.